# Wordpress single database connection

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a separate file in root directory of my blog and i need do some operations with database.
What i need to include in this file to work with wp database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include this into your script before you use any global WordPress variables or functions.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( '/path/to/your/wordpress/root/directory/wp-blog-header.php' );
status_header( 200 );
```

This will give you access to the WordPress functionality that you require such as the `$wpdb` global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function...

```
function get_wpdb_instance($file, $user, $pass, $name, $host='localhost') {
    $wpdb = true;
    function is_multisite() { return false; }
    function wp_die($message) {}
    require_once $file;
    return new wpdb($user, $pass, $name, $host);
}
```

Then in a function do the following changing the wp-db.php path as required.

```
$wpdb = get_wpdb_instance('../wp-includes/wp-db.php', 'username', 'password', 'database_name', 'localhost');
```

Then you can use $wpdb as you wish in that function...

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"), ARRAY_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the wp-config.php to get database informations and after simply open a connection with your db with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) for example.

If you want to use the [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Interfacing_With_the_Database) class, try to **include "wp-includes/wp-db.php"** and create a new instance of it.